# suggestions on fulltext search or already existing search algorithms

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

Can someone suggest how to solve the below search problem easily, I mean is there any algorithm, or full text search will be suffice for this?

There is below classification of items data,

| ItemCategory | ItemCluster | ItemSubCluster | SubCluster | Items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vegetable | Root vegetables | Root | WithOutSkin | potato, sweet potato, yam |
| Vegetable | Root vegetables | Root | WithSkin | onion, garlic, shallot |
| Vegetable | Greens | Leafy green | Leaf | lettuce, spinach, silverbeet |
| Vegetable | Greens | Cruciferous | Flower | cabbage, cauliflower, Brussels sprouts, broccoli |
| Vegetable | Greens | Edible plant stem | Stem | celery, asparagus |

The inputs will be some thing like,

sweet potato, yam
Yam, Potato
garlik, onion
lettuce, spinach, silverbeet
lettuce, silverbeet
lettuce, silverbeet, spinach

From the input, I want to get the mapping of the input items those belongs to which ItemCategory, ItemCluster, ItemSubCluster, SubCluster.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `silverbeet lettuce, silverbeet lettuce, silverbeet,` I'm confused. Is that pairs separated by commas, by blanks, or solitary items? `items those belongs to which [hierarchical categories]` is no better.

Comment: Thank you for your response @greybeard. The input will be comma separated. I 've modified the question. One thing I missed in my question is, the Items may come under different  ItemCategory or ItemCluster or ItemSubCluster. For example silverbeet may come under Leafy green and Cruciferous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly following the right approach.

You don't need full text searching here.

What you can create here is a kind of inverted index as follows:

If we take example of `potato`, create a map for `potato` storing what is its ItemCategory, ItemCluster, ItemSubCluster, SubCluster.

For example -

```
"potato": {
    "ItemCategory": "Vegetable",
    "ItemCluster": "Root vegetables",
    "ItemSubcluster": "Root",
    "Subcluster": "Without Skin"
}
```

Now, to store this kind of data for each vegetable would be expensive.

You can optimise the storage by using an encoding scheme:

For example -

let `ItemCategory` be denoted by `0`,
let `ItemCluster`  be denoted by `1`,
let `ItemSubcluster`  be denoted by `2`,
let `Subcluster`  be denoted by `3`

and the values be denoted by a similar encoding scheme:

let `Vegetable` be denoted by `0`,
let `Root vegetables` be denoted by `1`,
let `Root` be denoted by `2`,
let `Without Skin` be denoted by `3`

Now, your mapping becomes:

```
"potato": {
    "0": "0",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2",
    "3": "3",
}
```

To further optimise this, you can also make maintain an index of vegetables. For example, `potato` can be denoted by `0`.

So your final index becomes:

```
"0": {
    "0": "0",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2",
    "3": "3",
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Deepak for you detailed suggestion. One thing I missed out to mention in my question is the Items may come under different ItemCategory or ItemCluster or ItemSubCluster. Like the potato could exist in different categories. For example silverbeet may come under Leafy green and Cruciferous. But let me try with the suggession given by you. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, I will do that @Deepak